# How to pass Data from graphicQL to React component with gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, graphiql

I am trying to pass the Images through GraphicQL to my Banner component, which is a fragment component.. This code worked in my index.js but does not work when i try to create a new component.

I tried with class componennt aswell but same result

```
import React from 'react';
import Img from 'gatsby-image';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

const Banner = ({ data }) => (
    <div className="imageContainer">
         {console.log(data)}
            <Img fluid={data.image1.childImageSharp.fluid}/>
            <Img fluid={data.image2.childImageSharp.fluid}/>
            <Img fluid={data.image3.childImageSharp.fluid}/> 
    </div>
)

export const bannerImg = graphql`
   fragment bannerImg on File {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid{
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      }
    }
  }
`

export const query = graphql`
query {
    image1: file(relativePath: { eq: "images/one.jpg" }){
      ...bannerImg
    }

    image2: file(relativePath: { eq: "images/two.jpg" }){
      ...bannerImg
    }

    image3: file(relativePath: { eq: "images/three.jpg" }){
      ...bannerImg
    }
  }
`

export default Banner;
```

I expected something get pass as props but the component doesnt receive anything

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: hmm i think the problem is that its not a page component just a regular one, so i need to use <StaticQuery> ?, the message i get is TypeError: Cannot read property 'image1' of undefined

Comment: Did you try with a StaticQuery?

Comment: have not done it yet, reading the syntax, care to show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [docs for StaticQuery](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/)

```
import React from 'react'
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Img from 'gatsby-image'

export const bannerImg = graphql`
   fragment bannerImg on File {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid{
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      }
    }
  }
`

const Banner () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query BannerQuery {
        image1: file(relativePath: { eq: "images/one.jpg" }){
          ...bannerImg
        }

        image2: file(relativePath: { eq: "images/two.jpg" }){
          ...bannerImg
        }

        image3: file(relativePath: { eq: "images/three.jpg" }){
          ...bannerImg
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <div className="imageContainer">
        <Img fluid={data.image1.childImageSharp.fluid}/>
        <Img fluid={data.image2.childImageSharp.fluid}/>
        <Img fluid={data.image3.childImageSharp.fluid}/> 
      </div>
    )}
  />
)

export default Banner
```